# Needing to get data from inside of Div Id

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to get time stamp info from inside a Div ID.

Sadly the actual link only works in network but this is the section of the code that inspector shows for the time stamp. I use that page to pull metrics for our department at work, but I am pulling in the CSV file data. The html webpage shows when the data was last updated letting me know if the csv data I have is current our still not up to date. I was wondering if there was a way I could set up a query to look at only that portion of the html code from the webpage. currently my code for looking at the page in its entirety is this. This works to get the whole page and will show me the time stamp but its rather slow and I was wondering of a way to get only the time stamp and maybe that would work faster?

```html
<div id="timestamps">
    <!--
    [/reports/timestampDrilldown?resourceVersionKeysString=H4sIAAAAAAAAAK2QzS4EQRSFr_ETC_G3s7eSVI2eaa07FggRom0MEna3a2739Kj-UVUzxiwkFp5AiGcQSwnxAN7GG1joJkPs3UUt7jlV53z1-A6jWsFMG7vIOyaWfBt1q0HmdfP69u7l2R4G6OXnEwAwvboG5VQKf4AJ9rOUh0ImPM-UQclNnJA2mOSad5RskcxJ8X3SWUcJOvgRD5Xc_tLmG6RilHEfA0kD3xEpHWfpLl083YjOydXHQwUqPkxJ1GajReKUmptoyMC0X1aulpWr5WbFhxn195GdpoHZb5vENKo2jIrTaKWXFwCTv8Dl7Vb7amj32Mx9044DDLVH7l_eegYIk35qFaC8a_GtDX_vB4ntpAVRKmig-Bhkao-KFKHXo0hRhCZTfNHDoI7CZeiFFrNrVGNB3XWYt1yzncBzhHCX9BlcFh9bnmOD-OeFf4mn5dC2mmHInNCtMbvuIsO6WGTOEtmuILvpWVbvEzuwcCgHAgAA&warehouseId=BFI4]
    -->
    Data last checked at <d class="resourceDrilldownLink" title="57 minutes ago">2019/04/09 17:14 PDT</d>
</div>
```

```
 Sub DataLastChecked()
'
' DataPull Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim SD As Date
Dim ED As Date
Dim STS As Integer
Dim ETS As Integer
Dim STE As Integer
Dim ETE As Integer
SD = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
ED = Worksheets("Variables").Range("A2").Value
STS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B2").Value
ETS = Worksheets("Variables").Range("C12").Value
STE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
ETE = Worksheets("Variables").Range("D2").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'On Error GoTo Errorcatch

  If Worksheets("DataLastChecked").Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
  Worksheets("DataLastChecked").Visible = xlSheetVisible
 End If
 Sheets("DataLastChecked").Activate
 Sheets("DataLastChecked").Select
 Cells.Select
 Selection.ClearContents


 Sheets("DataLastChecked").Select
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://fclm-portal.amazon.com/reports/processPathRollup?reportFormat=HTML&warehouseId=BFI4&maxIntradayDays=1&spanType=Intraday&startDateIntraday=" & Year(SD) & "%2F" & Month(SD) & "%2F" & Day(SD) & "&startHourIntraday=" & (STS) & "&startMinuteIntraday=" & (STE) & "&endDateIntraday=" & Year(ED) & "%2F" & Month(ED) & "%2F" & Day(ED) & "&endHourIntraday=" & (ETS) & "&endMinuteIntraday=" & (ETE) & "&adjustPlanHours=true&_adjustPlanHours=on&_hideEmptyLineItems=on&employmentType=AllEmployees", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

       Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Sheets("Recap").Select
End With
If Worksheets("DataLastChecked").Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
  Worksheets("DataLastChecked").Visible = xlSheetHidden
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can issue an [xmlhttp request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) you could use the class name of the element. This code would go in a standard module. You open the VBE with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, then right click on Project Explorer window and add a standard module e.g. Module 1. Place code in there. You could then tie this code execution to a button or event. Change `ActiveSheet` for explicit sheet name reference.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTimeStamp()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "url", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = html.querySelector(".resourceDrilldownLink").innerText
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for helping!, How would I incorporate my link into that code that you posted? Sorry I've never tried using an xmlhttp request